# Starting an activity from an accessibility service doesn't work with Xiaomi

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, accessibilityservice, xiaomi

I have an accessibility service which has to open an activity when some conditions are met.

The code to open the activity is this:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(WindowChangeDetectingService.this, OpenActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

I've tried many other flags like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT` or `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, and set action as: `ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY`, but it doesn't start the activity.

I'm using a Xiaomi Mi9T and it doesn't work, but a colleague uses a Huawei and it does work for him, and on the emulator (Pixel phone) it works too. How can I fix this for the Xiaomi devices?

Answer (score 0):

**Xiaomi restricts apps from starting activity from the background by
default.** You'll have to guide users to manually allow it. (Official
MIUI announcement: https://www.xiaomi.cn/post/9216439  )

Open this intent and let the user manually allow the permission "start in the background":

```
    intent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.permissions.AppPermissionsEditorActivity");
```

How to know if the user has already allowed this permission? Here's
a piece of code found from the [Internet](https://blog.csdn.net/GuangkuoDing/article/details/100324162?utm_medium=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-blog-2%7Edefault%7EBlogCommendFromBaidu%7Edefault-7.control&depth_1-utm_source=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-blog-2%7Edefault%7EBlogCommendFromBaidu%7Edefault-7.control):

```
    public static boolean hasBackgroundStartPermissionInMIUI(Context context) {
        AppOpsManager ops = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        try {
          // ops.checkOpNoThrow(op, uid, packageName)
          Field field = AppOpsManager.class.getField("OP_BACKGROUND_START_ACTIVITY");
          field.setAccessible(true);
          int opValue = (int) field.get(ops);
          Method method = ops.getClass().getMethod("checkOpNoThrow", int.class, int.class, String.class);
          Integer result = (Integer) method.invoke(ops, opValue, Process.myUid(), context.getPackageName());
          return result == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED;
        } catch (Exception e) {
          ProductionEnv.throwExceptForDebugging(e);
          return false;
        }
      }
```

Additionally, for other permissions in the Xiaomi permission manager. Get a Xiaomi phone and query all the constants declared in `AppOpsManager`. Then replace the `declaredFields` with the permission you want.

Comment: Thanks! About number 2, in that same page you linked me it says that an `AccessibilityService` is an exception that would allow to start activites from the background, so I imagine that's not it.

I'll try number one but that looks promising, thank you very much!

Comment: @Stasky Oops, I didn't read the question carefully. I was thinking about starting activities from a normal service because that was exactly what I was facing last year and it took me a while to figure it out. Yes, an `AccessibilityService` is in the exception of the new restriction introduced in SDK29. I've modified the answer to prevent it from being misleading for others who found this question thread.

Comment: Sorry for coming back after a while, I haven't been able to work on it until recently. I can't get the intent to work, it says that I should declare the `"com.miui.securitycenter"` and `"com.miui.permcenter.permissions.AppPermissionsEditorActivity"` in the manifest, but these aren't my activities.

Comment: @Stasky, It doesn't need to be your activity, all you need is declare it in the manifest. You've misunderstood the problem, see [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element). Add this in manifest `<queries>
<package android:name="com.miui.securitycenter" />
</queries>`. And use `resolveActivityInfo()` to check if the activity exists and "exported = true", if the result is yes then you can open that activity with no problem.

Comment: I've added the following to the manifest:
```xml
<queries>
        <package android:name="com.miui.securitycenter" />
</queries>
```

And this code: 
```java
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.permissions.AppPermissionsEditorActivity");
ActivityInfo activityInfo = intent.resolveActivityInfo(getPackageManager(), 0);
startActivity(intent);
```

`activityInfo` is `null`, but I'm using it on the Xiaomi so should exist, and the logcat error is still asking if activity is declared in manifest.

Comment: That's weird, have you checked if your device has `com.miui.securitycenter` and `com.miui.permcenter.permissions.AppPermissionsEditorActivity` with `dumpsys`? The package/activity name can be changed on new firmware. Also, did you place <queries> flag correctly inside root level (it should be <manifest><queries></queries><application></application></manifest>)? Additionally, what I'm using is `ActivityInfo activityinfo = intent.resolveActivityInfo(context.getPackageManager(), PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);` and I also check `activityinfo.exported` to make sure activity is exported.

Comment: I feel like they might have changed the name of the activity. I've found some code which mentions the exact same thing you said for older MIUI, but to me it doesn't work, so it probably is that they changed it. I do have the `<queries>` flag correctly and I do the `activityInfo.exported` check, it's just that gives `nullPointerException` since `activityInfo == null`. This is pretty annoying, let's see if I find a workaround.